# How to set output voltage on this dual output buck converter board?

Tags: dc-dc-converter, buck

I guess this board's dual output voltage is configured by the EN terminal?
Resistance to ground? (Link to the eBay listing: [20W DC-DC Step UP & Down 5V-35V 12V 24V to ±5V ±9V ±12V ±15V Dual Power Supply](https://www.ebay.co.uk/itm/183347316904).)

These are cheap on eBay, but I bet they arrive undocumented and there is no indication of how to set the voltage on the listing. I've asked the seller and had no reply as yet. I would be very grateful for advice, it looks a very good solution for powering a graphic EQ module.

[image: Board Layout]

[image: Board Top View]

[image: Board Bottom View]

Comment: Can you figure out what is the controller/converter chip from the markings on it?

Comment: If the seller won't provide that information readily then you should buy elsewhere.

Comment: The chip seems to be deliberately obscured.

Comment: Thank you, I'd be glad of a lead as to where to buy elsewhere at a remotely comparable price: I'm looking for a cheap simple solution. Chinese boards are second rate but good enough for many purposes: the only significant problem I've had with them is nonexistent or incomprehensible documentation, which is why I try to anticipate that issue. I have a dozen similar but single output converters, all work fine, but all came with a trimpot installed. This is more enigmatic...

Comment: Looks like a DC DC converter to me, without a datasheet I can only speculate as to how it functions

Comment: @RobFawcett it's probably a clone anyway

Comment: The chip is probably a XLSemi XL6019 or similar and the schematic looks like an implementation of the dual output SEPIC configuration reference design.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Note that as always when asking for help on someone else's product, this is an educated guess about possible explanations. You can only get a definite answer from someone who knows that specific product. As one of the moderators here correctly points out: We are not tech support for Ebay sellers :-)

In the [Ebay listing you mentioned](https://www.ebay.co.uk/itm/183347316904), the lack of documentation and the deliberately obscured part number of the main IC would be enough to stop me from buying that module. Without that part number, I can't easily lookup the datasheet of the IC (without spending lots of time searching for ICs which match that pinout). With that part number, reverse-engineering the rest of the circuit would be simple.

However to answer your question, and since that Ebay listing doesn't allow you to choose one of the listed output voltages, here is one hypothesis since the listing you linked says:

> > Output voltage: **adjustable** ( test: ± 5v 12w 77%  / ± 9v 15w 84% / ± 12v 20w 86% / ± 15v 20w 88% )

(My emphasis above.)

In other words, the *fixed* voltages mentioned in the listing (±5V, ±9V etc.) are just *examples*.

After some searching, I found this almost identical PCB but with a variable resistor exactly where we would expect to see one, varying voltage to a feedback pin on a typical regulator:

[image: PCB photo from Ebay listing]

(Cropped image from [this Ebay listing](https://www.ebay.com/itm/323267901547))

The Ebay listing with that PCB photo has a very similar description to yours: "[20W DC-DC Step UP & Down 5V-35V 12V to ±5V ±9V ±12V ±15V Dual Power Supply Board](https://www.ebay.com/itm/323267901547)" but as you see, I have highlighted the **variable resistor** which is present on that board.

So possibilities for the confusion on the listing you mentioned include:

1. The photo on the listing you gave is correct for a single, fixed voltage board and you really would get a fixed voltage board, without being able to specify the voltage when you buy it.

   That means that some of the *text* in the listing (which specifies a *variable* output voltage) is wrong. Or...
2. The photo in the listing you gave is wrong, and the board being shipped is actually like the one shown in the photo above, with a variable resistor to change the output voltage. That would match with the description text saying that the output voltage is variable, and would mean that the photo in the listing you gave is wrong.

I don't see any way for the photo in your listing *and* the text in that listing, to both be correct.

However, as you said, it will likely come without documentation (as such boards typically do from Ebay) and you cannot expect the vendor to actually know anything about it (many are just warehouses / resellers, with no technical knowledge about what they sell). This is the risk you take, when buying from such vendors.

Comment: Thank you *so* much SamGibson for going to so much trouble. I didn’t know when I asked whether there might be some convention for the implementation of such boards which made documentation trivial and even needless for those familiar with them. Evidently not, and clearly my best option is to buy a board such as that which you found. Thank you again, sincerely, Rob

Comment: PS I did suspect continuously variable not fixed discrete voltages: I guess they list voltages within that range which buyers might need and put in the search box on eBay. I take the point about not being tech support for eBay sellers, but cheap components are a great route into experimentation and discovery. I've often got started on something only because I found a board or component I could afford to experiment with. Though I admit an undocumented board is a bad candidate: in this case I'm just looking to take a cheap fun project one step further & the spec of this board is perfect for that

Comment: @Rob - You're welcome :-) Unfortunately the lack of the datasheet for the IC (whose part number has been removed in the photo of the other board which I found too!) means that we can't be *sure* of anything. However, based on experience of common single-chip switch regulators, it seems "your" listing's photo is a board with a fixed voltage output - yet that contradicts the text. Not the first time I've seen such contradiction on eBay! If this has answered your question, please consider accepting it, to mark it as solved (see [here](https://electronics.stackexchange.com/help/someone-answers)).

Answer (score 2):

> I guess this boards dual output voltage is configured by the EN terminal?

I'd say that the ad is telling you that that the devices are available in four different dual-voltage options.

The EN pin is most likely to be an ENable pin which will turn the output on or off. It is most likely a digital input so you don't have the option of programming a particular output voltage.

> These are cheap on eBay but I bet they arrive undocumented ...

Our advice, as always is, "No datasheet? No sale!"

Comment: It specifies 'Output voltage adjustable'

Comment: https://rover.ebay.com/rover/0/0/0?mpre=https%3A%2F%2Fwww.ebay.co.uk%2Fulk%2Fitm%2F183347316904

Comment: "*It specifies 'Output voltage adjustable'*". Not in your question, it doesn't.

Comment: True, in a court of law, but my question was how to set the output voltage...